# No Session found for current thread: Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 (Using @PostConstruct annotation)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I read tons of posts by people with similar problems but I still can't make my code work.

The "`No Session found for current thread`" arises when I moved my `@Transactional` from the Dao to the service layer. Indeed, I'm convinced that binding a transaction to a single access is a waste of resources. By the way, my web-app configuration is very common:

- Spring 3.1.2
- Hibernate 4

I can't figure out the problem, I checked that the famous `<tx:annotation-driven>` is in the right place as well as the correct `<context:component-scan ...>`. My guess is that spring needs that `@Transactional` is also placed on top of classes having a session factory reference but it seems a little illogical to me.

here's the **servlet**

```
<!-- auto-detects and registers annotated classes belonging to the base package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.controllers" />
<!-- flips on all the annotation-driven capabilities for Spring MVC -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
...
```

here's the **context**

```
<!-- enables the @Transactional annotantions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- auto-detects and registers annotated classes belonging to the base package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.aop" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.model" />


<bean id="dataSource"
class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver.className}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.uri}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->       
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30" />
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>          
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

here's the **service**

```
package com.x.y.service.initialization;

@Component
public class Initializer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDaoImpl")
    private UserDao userDao;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void init()
    {
        ProfiledUser admin = userDao.loadByUsername("Administrator");

        ...
    }
}
```

and here's the **DAO**

```
package com.x.y.model.dao;

@Repository(value="userDaoImpl")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ProfiledUser loadByUsername(String username)
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProfiledUser.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        ProfiledUser user = (ProfiledUser) criteria.uniqueResult();
        if(user != null)
            return user;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

and here's the **stacktrace**

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
    at com.x.y.model.dao.UserDaoImpl.loadByUsername(UserDaoImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.loadByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.x.y.service.initialization.Initializer.init(Initializer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps its an erroneus configufation as implied by other answers, however, keep in mind that you should not annotate your `@PostConstruct` with `@Transactional` and expect it to work. At the point when the `@PostConstruct` is executed there is not guarantee that the your code is instrumented with the transactional semantics. The reason is that `@PostConstruct` only guarantees that all the dependencies got injected and that the bean construction is completed, but it doesn't mean that the complete context has finished loading (no guarantees that the transactional instrumentation has been done).

If you really need transactions in your `@PostConstruct`, go for the programmatic way. These are just my two cents, but could very well be an the cause to your issue

UPDATE

Just found a [blog](http://www.tikalk.com/java/doing-transactional-work-spring-service-using-postconstruct-method) about it, where they advise the usage of `@PostInitialize` as it guarantees to be called after the complete context is loaded

Comment: this can be an issue. Please consider that my `Initializer` class should run when the application is ready to go. Probably `@PostConstruct` is an overkill. Do you suggest any other annotation to say:"ok, the web-app is fully loaded, now executed this method."

Comment: yeps, just edited an answer @PostiInitialize should work, if not, you can inject TransactionManager and  use TransactionTemplate to handle the transaction programatically (leaving the @PostConstruct)

Comment: you won the race. It was definitely the PostConstruct issue. With @PostInitialize everything is going smooth as the oil. I'm going to change the title of my question so that people can properly address the problem.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't be able to make the PostInitialize annotation work. I annotate the method but simple it doesn't fire at startup. Online there's few information, can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

You declare  the 'data source' and the 'session factory', but you are missing he 'transactional manager'

try adding this to the spring context:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: the transaction manager is included in the context, more or less at line 3, right below the `<tx:annotation-driven>`.

Comment: Sorry I did not see it :-O

Answer (score 0):

You can define transaction manager  in hibernate-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hbnTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="hbnTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: please note that the transaction manager is already in the context file. More or less ay line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are directly making use of `SessionFactory` in your DAO you must have the following configuration `hibernate.current_session_context_class` and your `SessionFactory` configuration should look like below.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop> 
            <!-- Add this configuration -->
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>          
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I was using annotation based configuration, I have configured sessionfactory, datasource and transaction manager every thing. but I did not give @EnableTransactionManagement annotation at AppConfig class.

The code looks like below after adding the transaction annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bmp.*")
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:${env}.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {
-----
}
```

The above annotations resolved my problem.

Vote up if this solves, your problem.